# How to subset a data frame by taking only the Non NA values of 2 columns in this data frame

Tags: r, missing-data, subset

I am trying to subset a data frame by taking the integer values of 2 columns om my data frame

```
Subs1<-subset(DATA,DATA[,2][!is.na(DATA[,2])] & DATA[,3][!is.na(DATA[,3])])
```

but it gives me an error :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

How can I construct a subset which is composed of NON NA values of column 2 AND column 3?

Thanks a lot?

Comment: I'd try `DATA[complete.cases(DATA[, 2:3]), ]` - all rows except those with NA in column 2 and column 3.

Comment: I have never used tihs statement luke, could you provide me the whole line in R syntax?

Comment: This is very basic and there's plenty of information on the web: https://www.google.com/search?q=r+subsetting. Also look at `?complete.cases`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
Subs1<-subset(DATA, (!is.na(DATA[,2])) & (!is.na(DATA[,3])))
```

The second parameter of `subset` is a logical vector with same length of `nrow(DATA)`, indicating whether to keep the corresponding row.

Comment: thaks a lot @cogitovita

Answer (score 13):

The na.omit functions can be an answer to you question

```
 Subs1 <- na.omit(DATA[2:3])
```

[https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/na.fail.html]

Answer (score 3):

Here an example.
a,b ,c are 3 vectors which a and b have a missing value.
once they are created i use cbind in order to bind them in one matrix which afterwards you can transform to data frame.

The final result is a dataframe where 2 out of 3 columns have a missing value.
So we need to keep only the rows with complete cases.`DATA[complete.cases(DATA), ]`  is used in order to keep only these rows that have not missing values in every column. `subset` object is these rows that have complete cases.

```
  a <- c(1,NA,2)
  b <- c(NA,1,2)
  c <- c(1,2,3)
  DATA <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
  subset <-  DATA[complete.cases(DATA), ]
```